# ./install_bam.sh and i get an error stating "cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, ssh

Eu estou tentando instalar uma software. Quando tento executar o chmod + x ./install_bam.sh comando para obter a permissão para executar o ./install_bam.sh eu recebo um erro dizendo "cannot execute binary file".

As permissões do arquivo estão bem. Eu tentei fazê-lo como root também.

Alguma pista, ideias?

Answer (score 0):

Tente: chmod +x install_bam.sh

Sintaxe do comando chmod:

> chmod [-fv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] mode file ... 
>     chmod [-fv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a] ACE file ... 
>     chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E] file ... 
>     chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-C] file ... 
>     chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-N] file ...

ou seja:

> chmod +flags arquivo 
>   chmod mode arquivo

[fonte](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chmod/)